# A special type of transformation for columns of a matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

so i was wondering if there exist some kind of transformation matrix like 'T' such that for matrix A, "AT" replaces some parts of two columns (not all entries). like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1\\
2 & 5 & 3\\
1 & 6 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

which if it gets multiplied by T the result will be:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1\\
2 & 3 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 6
\end{bmatrix}

as we can see some part of the third column has been replaced by column 2.

Comment: This is essentially just solving $AT = M \iff T = A^{-1}M$, where $M$ is your desired resulting matrix.

Comment: what if A is not a squared matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a two-sided linear transformation that accomplishes your goal. Specifically, let $$E = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ be the matrix such that $EA$ isolates the first row of $A$ and nullifies the rest and let $$S = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ be the matrix such that the second and third columns of $AS$ have been swapped compared with $A$. Then the matrix you seek can be computed as
$$ B = EA + (I-E)AS $$
where $I$ is the 3-by-3 identity matrix. It is clear that $A \rightarrow B(A)$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't think of that. :)

Comment: Thanks! i wonder what would be the case where A is not a square matrix

Comment: @Saoshyant   The same principle applies if A is m by n. Only E is m by m and S is n by n.

Comment: @CarlChristian thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is that you want one matrix $ T $ that does the same kind of thing (as you described) to any matrix $ A $.

There is no such matrix $ T $. One way you can view multiplying a matrix $ A $ by another matrix $ T $ on the right is performing a linear transformation on each row of $ A $. The important thing is that you perform *the same* transformation on each row of $ A $. Therefore, for example, if all rows of $ A $ were identical, then all rows of $ AT $ would have to be identical as well.

For example, let
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and suppose we want to swich the bottom two elements of $ A $. There is no matrix $ T $ satisfying
$$
AT =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
because if $ AT $ is defined, both rows of $ AT $ are equal to (the row times matrix product)
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} T
$
and therefore equal to each other.

Comment: sorry if i did not ask my question clearly. my understanding is that multiplying A by some arbitrary matrix (from right : AX) is equivalent to writing a linear combination of  A's columns , right? therefore according to you there is no linear combination of A's columns that results in what i desire?

Comment: I think you asked clearly enough. You are also right about the columns, but that is only one of several equivalent ways to view matrix multiplication (our professor called them "column perspective", "row perspective" etc). I will add an example to my answer to show what I mean.

I don't know, whether there is a suitable linear combination of $A$'s column, where $A$ is the specific matrix in your post. But there is no *uniform* way (independent on $ A $) of choosing linear combinations of a (general) matrix $ A $ (that is, a fixed choice of $ X $) that does what you want.

Comment: ... combination of *the columns* of a (general) matrix ... *