# Shifting Rows in a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have the following matrix:

```
      a  b  c
M = [ d  e  f ]
      g  h  i
```

How can I cycle rows, so that the first entry comes around to the back, like so:

```
          b  c  a 
M * ? = [ d  e  f ]
          g  h  i
```

The first row is an example. Ideally there is an operation that can use a vector indicating the number of cycles, like so:

```
          2      c  a  b 
M * ? * [-1] = [ f  d  e ]
          0      g  h  i
```

Is it possible to do that just using multiplication?

I was thinking that this looks like a form of rotation. In a 2D Vectorspace it would mean to swap the coordinates around. That can be done using the unit matrix. Does it work the same for nD matrices?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586282/a-special-type-of-transformation-for-columns-of-a-matrix/4586293 
Also, in general, what do you get when you multiply matrix * (column) vector?

Comment: Well for the 1st one We can choose a Elementary Matrix of switching rows.

Comment: Well for the 2nd one choose a matrix K that behaves M*K=Matrix in the 2nd question and search for K*[p,q,r]^t=[2 -1,0]^t but K is a Elementary matrix hence if it's determinant is non-zero(think zero is even possible or not in case of Elementary matrices). THEN YES WE ARE DONE.